# Document-oriented dbms as primary db and a RDBMS db as secondary db?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, solr, document-oriented-db

I'm having some performance issues with MySQL database due to it's normalization.

Most of my applications that uses a database needs to do some heavy nested queries, which in my case takes a lot of time. Queries can take up 2 seconds to run, *with indexes*. Without indexes about 45 seconds.

A solution I came a cross a few month back was to use a faster more linear document based database, in my case Solr, as a primary database. As soon as something was changed in the MySQL database, Solr was notified.

This worked really great. All queries using the Solr database only took about *3ms*.

The numbers looks good, but I'm having some problems.

- Huge database

The MySQL database is about 200mb, the Solr db contains about 1.4Gb of data.
Each time I need to change a table/column the database need to be reindexed, which in this example took over 12 hours.

- Difficult to render both a Solr object and a Active Record (MySQL) object without getting [wet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

The view is relying on a certain object. It doesn't care if the object it self is an Active Record object or an Solr object, as long as it can call a set of attributes on the it.

Like this.

```
# Controller
@song = Song.first

# View
@song.artist.urls.first.service.name
```

The problem in my case is that the data being returned from Solr is flat like this.

```
{
  id: 123,
  song: "Waterloo",
  artist: "ABBA",
  service_name: "Groveshark",
  urls: ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
}
```

This forces me to build an active record object that can be passed to the view.

**My question**

Is there a better way to solve the problem?
Some kind of super duper fast primary read only database that can handle complex queries fast would be nice.

Comment: Do you have ID numbers in every table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solr individual fields update

About reindexing all on schema change: Solr [does not support updating individual fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_update_a_specific_field_of_an_existing_document.3F) yet, but there is a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-139) about this that's still unresolved. However, how many times do you change schema?

### MongoDB

If you can live without a RDBMS (without joins, schema, transactions, foreign key constrains), a document-based DB like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), 
or CouchDB would be a perfect fit. ([here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB) is a good comparison between them )

Why use MongoBD:

- data is in native format (you can use an ORM mapper like [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/)  directly in the views, so you don't need to adapt your records as you do with Solr)
- [dynamic queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying)
- very good performance on non-full text search queries
- schema-less (no need for migrations)
- build-in, easy to setup [replication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets)

Why use SOLR:

- advanced, very performant full-text search

Why use MySQL

- joins, constrains, transactions

### Solutions

So, the solutions (combinations) would be:

1. Use MongoDB + Solr

   - but you would still need to reindex all on schema change
2. Use only MongoDB

   - but drop support for advanced full-text search
3. Use MySQL in a master-slave configuration, and balance reads from slave(s) (using a plugin like [octupus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus)) + Solr

   - setup complexity
4. Keep current setup, denormalize data in MySQL

   - messy

### Solr reindexing slowness

> The MySQL database is about 200mb, the Solr db contains about 1.4Gb of
>   data. Each time I need to change a table/column the database need to
>   be reindexed, which in this example took over 12 hours.

Reindexing 200MB DB in Solr *SHOULD NOT* take 12 hours! Most probably you have also other issues like:

MySQL:

- [n+1 issue](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/29-fix-n-1-queries)
- indexes

SOLR:

- commit after each request - this is the default setup is you use a plugin like sunspot, but it's a [perf killer for production](http://blog.raspberry.nl/2011/04/08/solr-update-performance/)

From http://outoftime.github.com/pivotal-sunspot-presentation.html:

> - By default, Sunspot::Rails commits at the end of every request
>     that updates the Solr index. Turn that off.
>
>   - Use Solr's autoCommit
>       functionality. That's configured in solr/conf/solrconfig.xml
>   - Be
>       glad for assumed inconsistency. Don't use search where results need to
>       be up-to-the-second.

- other setup issues (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Indexing_Performance)

Look at the logs for more details

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing your data into Solr to flatten the records, why don't you just create a separate table in your MySQL database that is optimized for read only access.

Also you seem to contradict yourself

> The view is relying on a certain object. It doesn't care if the object it self is an Active Record object or an Solr object, as long as it can call a set of attributes on the it.
>
> The problem in my case is that the data being returned from Solr is flat... This forces me to build a fake active record object that can be rendered by the view.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 'contradict' part. The view wants an object that looks like this `@song.artist.urls.first.service.name`. Solr doesn't provide that, so I've to build one by my self. In other words, the view doesn't care if the object is an AR object, as long as the just mentioned attribute exists.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Thought you were saying you always needed to convert to an AR object b/c you were building a fake one and just prior to that you had said your view did not care... Now I see, since it just needs the attribute.